# What is the best correct way to iterate through the "columns and rows" of a string matrix in Java?

Tags: java, string, loops

I know how to do it for one string:

```
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
    char c = string.charAt(i);        
}
```

but when I have something like a String [][] how it works?

Comment: Use a double for loop to iterate over rows and columns.

Comment: What are you asking here -- iterating over a two-dimensional _character_ array (i.e. `String[]`) or a two-dimensional _string_  array (`String[][]`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to access the values then you can use for-each loops:

```
for (String[] row: array) {
    for (String value: row) {
        // use value
    }
}
```

This won't work if you want to change the values. In that case you need to have the indices available. You can use traditional for loops for that (as referenced in the other answers) or, in Java 8, `IntStream`:

```
IntStream.range(0, array.length).forEach(r ->
    IntStream.range(0, array[r].length).forEach(c -> {
        // use array[r][c]
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have double array/two dimensional array for the following to iterate through it:

```
String[][] str = new String[10][5];// Meaning it has 10 rows and 5 columns
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){//This will iterate through 10 rows
   for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){//For each row it will iterate through 5 columns
      System.out.println(str[i][j]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something along the lines of this to iterate through *rows* and *columns*.

```
int row = 5;
int column = 5;
String[][] table = new String[row][column];

for(int r = 0; r < row; r++){
    for(int c = 0; c < column; c++){
         System.out.println(table[r][c]);
    }
}
```